# MVC servlets JSP javabeans- how many javabean classes should i have?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, servlets, javabeans

hey there! this is just a general enquiry.. so far, i have one servlet which sends dispatches actions around, many JSP files.. but my question is- how many javabeans files does a typical web application like flickr have? so far, i have only 1- but it has a lotta get and set methods. is this okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, not every web application is written in Java, and although Flick might be written partially, it's not using it entirely.

Next, your question about usage of JavaBeans is definitely very general. One bean should exist for each "entity" in your application, and what an entity is, your application defines.

Also, this number varies based on what technology you're using. Some frameworks require you to use beans for many things (JSF), while others do not.

So, before asking for number of beans for existing project, you should determine what your project actually uses and, depending on it's size, it will have more or less beans.

I suggest you don't invent the wheel. If you want to use MVC in Java, I'd suggest using [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) since it's a very good MVC framework in my opinion.

Research before making assumptions. Amount of X, for X being something like line count, file count, or some other arbitrary thing, does not make a sucessful application.

Comment: thanks for your insight darioo.. this is a university assignment, however, and we're not to use frameworks.. in any case, we have the basic tagging, adding friends, recent activity functionality.. i only have a customer bean so far. thoughts?

Comment: @Dhruv: it depends on your design. You might want to have these beans: `Person` (can be a friend or a customer as subclasses), `Activity`, `Tag`... modelling entities and their relationships will help your understand your design and then it'll be easier to see what needs to be a Javabean. If you've seen database design, Javabeans shouldn't be too different. One bean = one entity. One relationship = getter/setter inside of bean for another bean.

Answer (score 1):

Since your project is pretty simplistic using servlets, you can start with one bean, and then break it into several as the complexity grows.  It's a good idea to have related functionality grouped together, instead of a single, massive collection of code ;o)

I'm sure large websites are complex and have TONS of beans. JSF is used often, so you'd have managed beans, and probably stateless or stateful EJB's also.  In those kind of projects, servlets are used for more specialized tasks, such as playing audio or allowing users to download binaries.

Comment: say my bean has like 15 getter and 15 setter methods. is that too much?

Comment: That's not unheard of, but if you have chunks of related code, you can break them into separate beans to keep it better organized.